# Using Haxe to output JavaScript

Tags: javascript, haxe

Is anyone using Haxe to output to JavaScript for their front end web development?

Is there an Eclipse plugin that supports autocompletion?

Can you point me to any good tutorials?

Can't find any other than the getting started page on the Haxe site.

Comment: Maybe FDT - "a flexible development toolkit in Eclipse for interactive developers": http://fdt.powerflasher.com/

Comment: Take a look at [eclihx](http://code.google.com/p/eclihx/)

Answer (score 4):

You might also enjoy visiting http://www.haxejs.com for some more resources and examples for creating haxe JS applications :)

Answer (score 2):

For IDE I would recomend FlashDevelop, it has good code completion and generally good Haxe support. If you want to make things simple use the JQueryExtern Library, basicly a wrapper for jQuery 1.6.1 with as strict typing as possible.

For examples I would check the examples in the Haxe site: http://haxe.org/doc/targets/js and then build upon this.

Comment: That haxe url seems to be outdated. Can we include the content in the answer for posterity?